# Why can't I install SQL Server SP1 (KB968369)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, windows-server-2008

I have a Windows Server 2008 x64 machine. I have the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB968368)" as an "optional" update available from Windows Update. I choose to install it, my computer installs it for a while, I restart, and that update is available again. Why doesn't my computer install it?

Thank you.

Comment: Agreed. I'll think better next time :)

Comment: daniel thank you for contributing your wisdom to this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I deleted the PendingFileRenameOperation key in the registry (backed up that registry branch first), ran the install, restarted and it is now in my installed updates list.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but I had the same problem. Did you ever do an "Edition Upgrade" in the SQL Server 2008 installer? Many users who did such an upgrade are reporting problems with the update package. For me, it wasn't a mission-critical system, so I just uninstalled the whole shebang and then reinstalled.

Other workarounds at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=431591). These people have problems when it's installed on the same machine as Visual Studio.

FWIW, I find the entire setup experience for SQL Server 2008 to be absolutely miserable.

Comment: Nope, I did a clean install. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Every SQL installations are miserable... not only 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the same problem before. I googled around and found that's a known issue My solution is to check something like "don't notify this updates".

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to install and disappear off my list! I know, it's not an ideal world :). I had problems adding features to SQL Server, it would complain that reboot required even after I rebooted; I had to hack the registry to get features to install.

Comment: Have you checked your SQL version to see if the SP was already installed? If I recall, the problem was somehow AutoUpdate thinks the sp1 wasn't installed even if it was.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any errors in your event log?

I found that I couldn't install it using windows update, I had to manually download it and it installed first time. I also has this problem for SQL 2005 sp2